# On OS X, how to grant network 192.168.3.* access to network 192.168.1.*?

Tags: networking, osx, routing, route, gateway

I connect to Wifi with OS X, it is network `192.168.1.*`. Then I also connect a second computer to Mac's ethernet port, which is configured as network `192.168.3.*`. I don't need the eth-box to access internet, but just to be able to access other machines on `192.168.1.*`, the network created by Wifi router. How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you described, first you have to configure your Mac OS X host to act as a router between networks 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24.

To do that, you should enable forwarding in that machine, which you can do with this command:

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

You might also want to add that configuration to /etc/sysctl.conf, so it's preserved on reboots.

Once that is done, you need to have routes configured on both sides so they know where to go for the machines of the other network.

For instance, in your Wifi router, you should configure a static route for 192.168.3.0/24 using as gateway the IP of your Mac OS X box on the 192.168.1.0/24 network. That way, when other machines in the Wifi network send traffic to 192.168.3.x, the router will redirect to your OS X box (which will route it to the other interface, since forwarding is enabled.)

On your box on the 192.168.3.0/24 network, you might need to do a similar setup, configuring a static route to reach 192.168.1.0/24 network through the IP of your Mac OS X box on the 192.168.3.0/24 network. (This latter route might be unnecessary if your Mac OS X is already the default gateway for that machine, in which case all the packets are already being routed to it anyways.)

The way to configure these routes will depend on the OS or software running on the other box and the Wifi router... Take a look at their manuals and see if you find any references for configuring static routes.